# Restore Clonezilla Disk Image to a Disk of a Different Size

Tags: 12.04, clonezilla, disk-image

I use Clonezilla at my school to save and restore disk Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows images over LAN.  When I try to restore an image to a computer with a disk whose size is not identical to the disk where the image was created, I cannot restore the image, even though it would clearly fit and work on this disk (i.e. restore a 7GB disk image from a 40GB disk to a 60GB disk).  How can I force Clonezilla to do this?

Comment: Are you cloning disks or partitions? It may be useful to clone the partitions, even if there is only one partition in a disk. Restoring a smaller partition should work.

Comment: You have to use the same size disk if you are restoring the entire disk (the MBR contains information about disk size, start and end of partitions, and, that I know, it will not work to restore the MBR on different sized disks). Your other option is to make a backup partition by partition. You can then restore the data within a partition on different sized disks so long as the partition is the same size.

Comment: So, if I am backing up partitions, do I need to set up partitions on the target disk before restoring?  When I restore images, I want to wipe the disk clean each time.  Also, I would need to include a swap partition, right?