# Can I restore a partition image to a different sized partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, clonezilla

Possible [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291577/restore-clonezilla-disk-image-to-a-disk-of-a-different-size) but no one answered it clearly.

I had Linux Mint installed on a partition with size 10 GB. Since I was out of space, I tried to resize partition using GParted from Live boot. I had 10 GB unallocated space. But I failed to resize since the linux partition was out of extended partition and unallocated space was inside extended partition. So I used Clonezilla to create a partition image of the linux partition only. It's all history now. I managed to delete the Linux partition of 10GB and merged 10 GB unallocated space to an already existing partition. And then I created a new partition of 20 GB by shrinking the already existing partition.

Sorry for the long paragraph, my question is that, can I restore the linux partition image (partition size was 10 GB) created using Clonezilla to the newly created 20 GB partition? I have not backed up the whole hard disk, but backed up the single linux partition which had Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose, everything can be done using gparted. With the exception of / partition, any partition can can be resized in gparted by Rclick, select unmount, then resize.

Any partition (including /) can be cloned/copied to any space, of equal or greater size, by either of two methods. The most reliable method is using
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sd!!! of=/dev/sd@@@
where the Input Folder/File sd!!! is the partition you want to copy, and the Output Folder/File sd@@@ is the (unmounted) place you want to copy to.

The second method [$ copy if=/dev/sd!!! of=/dev/sd@@@] is less reliable.

Invariably there will remain empty space in the output folder/file. To use it, just click on 'Partition' in the gparted top-menu, select Disks from the dropdown menu, then 'repair' or somesuch

Comment: I used GParted and solved the issue. Thanks. :)